# controlled components in form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this form where I want the name and gender of the user and I change state accordingly but my code seems to fail as the output don't match what i want.
Here is the code.

```
class Addoption extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name:'',
      gender:''
    };
    this.handleaddoption=this.handleaddoption.bind(this);
  }
  handleaddoption(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const nameofuser=event.target.elements.nametext.value;
    const genderofuser=event.target.elements.gendertext.value;
    this.setState({
      name:nameofuser,
      gender:genderofuser
    });
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(this.state.gender);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <form >
       <input type="text" name="nametext" placeholder="name" onChange={this.handleaddoption}/>
       <input type="text" name="gendertext" placeholder="gender" onChange={this.handleaddoption}/>

      </form>
      </div>
    );  
  }
}

export default App;
```

When the user enters the name and the age ,I don't see his age and name in console instead error which says cannot read Cannot read property 'nametext' of undefined.
I tried one more method even that doesn't seem to work.

```
handleaddoption(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const nameofuser=event.target.elements.nametext.value;
    const genderofuser=event.target.elements.gendertext.value;
    this.setState({
      name:nameofuser,
      gender:genderofuser
    });
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(this.state.gender);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleaddoption}>
       <input type="text" name="nametext" placeholder="name" />
       <input type="text" name="gendertext" placeholder="gender"/>

      </form>
      </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

Comment: you are calling the onChange method from the input but instead trying to read elements of the form in the handler, since the input has no children the elements property return undefined.

Comment: can you tell me as how this is done or it can be achieved?

Comment: The event.target refers to the input, not the form

Comment: Yes, let me write a snippet

Comment: I added one more method that I tried to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the event a little different.

Your handler function receives an event object, and the event.target is actually the input.

Change your input names so you can directly reference the state with them.

Then check out the component lifecycle, you can't see the updates because of how the component rendering works in react. Notice I used the componentDidUpdate method which runs after the setState is completed and there the logs show the new state.

Here's the link to the lifecycle docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: '', gender: '' }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('gender 1', this.state.gender)
    console.log('name 1', this.state.name)
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

    console.log('gender', this.state.gender)
    console.log('name', this.state.name)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="gender" value={this.state.gender || ''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name || ''} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: please edit your code to show as how the above snipppet can be used to get gender and name of user.

Comment: If you are inside of the element you just need to call `this.state.name` or `this.state.gender`, only make sure that the `this` object is correctly bound.

Comment: handleaddoption(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(this.state.gender);
  }

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you also need to specify the value in the inputs, I edited the code. If the inputs change when you type in them then you can be sure the state is changing, the code is not tested, hope it works now

Comment: i still don't see name and gender in console .

Comment: but the inputs are changing?

Comment: Please add a working snippet as this only creates more confsuin as i am not fully aware of the technqiue you mentioned.

Comment: I changed the code completely, now I tested it, the issue you are having is related to how react renders and updates components, you need to learn the component's lifecycle since it is a very essential part of react and will give you a much better understanding of how things work behind the scenes.